# Normalizing data and applying colormap results in rotated image using matplotlib?

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, matplotlib, fractals, chaos

So I wanted to see if I could make fractal flames using matplotlib and figured a good test would be the sierpinski triangle. I modified a working version I had that simply performed the chaos game by normalizing the x range from -2, 2 to 0, 400 and the y range from 0, 2 to 0, 200. I also truncated the x and y coordinates to 2 decimal places and multiplied by 100 so that the coordinates could be put in to a matrix that I could apply a color map to. Here's the code I'm working on right now (please forgive the messiness):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import random

def f(x, y, n):
    N = np.array([[x, y]])

    M = np.array([[1/2.0, 0], [0, 1/2.0]])

    b = np.array([[.5], [0]])
    b2 = np.array([[0], [.5]])

    if n == 0:
        return np.dot(M, N.T)

    elif n == 1:
       return np.dot(M, N.T) + 2*b

    elif n == 2:
        return np.dot(M, N.T) + 2*b2

    elif n == 3:
        return np.dot(M, N.T) - 2*b

def norm_x(n, minX_1, maxX_1, minX_2, maxX_2):
    rng = maxX_1 - minX_1
    n = (n - minX_1) / rng

    rng_2 = maxX_2 - minX_2
    n = (n * rng_2) + minX_2

    return n

def norm_y(n, minY_1, maxY_1, minY_2, maxY_2):
    rng = maxY_1 - minY_1
    n = (n - minY_1) / rng

    rng_2 = maxY_2 - minY_2
    n = (n * rng_2) + minY_2

    return n    

# Plot ranges
x_min, x_max = -2.0, 2.0
y_min, y_max = 0, 2.0

# Even intervals for points to compute orbits of
x_range = np.arange(x_min, x_max, (x_max - x_min) / 400.0)
y_range = np.arange(y_min, y_max, (y_max - y_min) / 200.0)

mat = np.zeros((len(x_range) + 1, len(y_range) + 1))   

random.seed()

x = 1
y = 1

for i in range(0, 100000):
    n = random.randint(0, 3)
    V = f(x, y, n)

    x = V.item(0)
    y = V.item(1)

    mat[norm_x(x, -2, 2, 0, 400), norm_y(y, 0, 2, 0, 200)] += 50

plt.xlabel('x0')
plt.ylabel('y')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(mat, cmap="spectral", extent=[-2,2, 0, 2])
plt.show()
```

The mathematics seem solid here so I suspect something weird is going on with how I'm handling where things should go into the 'mat' matrix and how the values in there correspond to the colormap.

[image]

Comment: What's the question? Maybe you can post the image you got and tell us how it's different from what you expected?

Comment: @arokem picture added. The tip of the triangle should be at (0, 2) not (2, 1) so that's what I meant by 'sideways'. My question is: Why is the triangle sideways and how do I fix it? What makes me think that the matrix data and how the colormap interprets it are to blame is that the code that this is based off of generates the triangle correctly.

Comment: Remember that numpy indexes (by default) c-style as [row, col], but we plot (x, y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you need to transpose your matrix using the method `.T`. So just replace

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(mat, cmap="spectral", extent=[-2,2, 0, 2])
plt.show()
```

by

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = gca()
ax.imshow(mat.T, cmap="spectral", extent=[-2,2, 0, 2], origin="bottom")
plt.show()
```

[image]

The argument `origin=bottom` tells to `imshow` to have the origin of your matrix at the bottom of the figure.

Hope it helps.